# Bootstrap 4: Limiting column height to a smaller column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have a element with class `row` and three `col` elements right after it. Right now, all `col` elements assume the height of the largest `col`.

I would like to restrict the column heights instead to that of a smaller column such that,

- This column, `#colB`, has a minimum height, but can be made bigger
- The other two columns should `overflow-y: scroll` if they exceed the height of `#colB`.

Is there a good way to do this using Bootstrap 4 utilities?

Example js-fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/fwtpeq43/4/

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35387368/setting-equal-height-for-divs-with-flexboxdepending-on-the-shortest-one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're okay with having a pre-defined height, you can set the height of the row and then the subsequent divs will overflow if they are taller than that height.

Otherwise, you'll have to use JavaScript to compare the heights of each of the divs, select the smallest one, and then set the height directly on the row element.

```
.row { height: 50vh; }
```

Comment: I've edited my post to be a little bit clearer, but basically what you're saying is there isn't really a way to restrict columns to the height of a specific sibling?

Comment: Not with CSS alone. You'll either need a predefined height or javascript's help

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript or jQuery on page load to get ***colB*** height and the update ***colA*** and ***colC*** height based on that.

I have attached
     [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h7sbuhfa/)

**OR**

Copy and paste this code just above your    `</body>`

```
<script>
  temp = $('#colB').height();
  console.log(temp);
  document.getElementById('colA').setAttribute("style","height:"+temp+"px");
  document.getElementById('colC').setAttribute("style","height:"+temp+"px"); 
</script>
```